How can I set my MSISDN in esim as CPBS is empty?
I use to set MSISDN for physical SIM card by
AT
OK
?
+CPBS: "SM",0,500
AT+CPBS="ON"
AT+CPBS?
+CPBS: "ON",0,3
OK
AT+CPBR=1
OK
AT+CPBW=,"+912345678"
OK
AT+CNUM
+CNUM: "","+912345678",145
OK
***However for esim I cannot set "ON"

there is no option to choose from
AT+CPBS=?
+CPBS: ()
AT+CPBS=ON
ERROR
AT+CPBS=?
+CPBS: ()
